# Calling function from array using setTimeout in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, settimeout

I am creating two function name call and call2 and putting this two functions in array x. In another function called timer i am trying to call this function every 2 seconds. But its giving error **expected an assigment or function call instead show and expression**.

And also i dont want this functions to run when i create an array.
this my code http://jsbin.com/IMiVadE/2/

```
function call(name)
{
  console.log("Hello " + name);
}

function call2()
{
  console.log("Hello world");
}

var x = [call("Nakib"), call2()];
var i = 0;

function timer(x, i)
{
  x[i];
  i++;
  if(i<x.length)
     window.setTimeout(timer(x, i), 2000);

}
timer(x, i);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some mistakes in your code:

- call2() calls the function. Correct: call2 is the reference to the function.
- x[i] accesses the value (the function reference). You need x[i]() to execute the function.

Here is your code working: http://jsbin.com/IMiVadE/6/edit

sayHello(name) is a function that generates new functions that output a specific "Hello ..." text.

```
function sayHello(name)
{
  return function () {
    console.log("Hello " + name);
  }
}

function timer(x, i)
{
  x[i]();
  if (i < x.length - 1) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      timer(x, i + 1);
    }, 2000);
  }
}

var x = [sayHello("Nakib"), sayHello("world")];

setTimeout(function () {
  timer(x, 0);
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` needs a function without parameter. So you can wrap the recursive call to `timer` in an anonymous function to fix that:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){timer(x, i)}, 2000);
```

Also, the first line in your timer function, consisting only of `x[i];`, is useless, although it probably isn't the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `setTimeout` function takes a function as a parameter, you are executing the `timer` function before it is passed and since `timer` doesn't return anything, `undefined` is being passed to the timeout;

```
window.setTimeout(timer(x, i), 2000); // is the same as...
window.setTimeout(undefined, 2000);
```

It should be;

```
window.setTimeout(function() { timer(x, i) }, 2000); // or...
window.setTimeout(timer.bind(this, x, i), 2000);
```

I'm not sure if this is intentional, but you are doing the same thing with your array;

```
var x = [call("Nakib"), call2()];
```

This will execute the functions and their results will be stored in the array. Is this what you want?

Comment: I dont want its result to be stored in an array but i want that function to be stored so i can call then in my timer() function.

Comment: @Nakib Okay, well you need to have another think about how your code works, and take a look at how `first class functions` work. Come back if you still need help afterwards. I hope this was helpful :)